# Consecration offering

Tags: leviticus, offering

In Leviticus 7:37 (KJV)

> 37 This is the law of the burnt offering, of the meat offering, and of the sin offering, and of the trespass offering, and of the **consecrations**, and of the sacrifice of the peace offerings;

What is the consecration offering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the ceremony when a new priest dressed in his liturgical vestments for the first time and received the congregation there was a special sacrifice. We can read more about it in Leviticus 8:22-30 (KJV)

> And he brought the other ram, the ram of consecration: and Aaron and his sons laid their hands upon the head of the ram.  And he slew it; and Moses took of the blood of it, and put it upon the tip of Aaron's right ear, and upon the thumb of his right hand, and upon the great toe of his right foot.  And he brought Aaron's sons, and Moses put of the blood upon the tip of their right ear, and upon the thumbs of their right hands, and upon the great toes of their right feet: and Moses sprinkled the blood upon the altar round about.  And he took the fat, and the rump, and all the fat that was upon the inwards, and the caul above the liver, and the two kidneys, and their fat, and the right shoulder:  And out of the basket of unleavened bread, that was before the Lord , he took one unleavened cake, and a cake of oiled bread, and one wafer, and put them on the fat, and upon the right shoulder:  And he put all upon Aaron's hands, and upon his sons' hands, and waved them for a wave offering before the Lord .  And Moses took them from off their hands, and burnt them on the altar upon the burnt offering: they were consecrations for a sweet savour: it is an offering made by fire unto the Lord .  And Moses took the breast, and waved it for a wave offering before the Lord : for of the ram of consecration it was Moses' part; as the Lord commanded Moses.  And Moses took of the anointing oil, and of the blood which was upon the altar, and sprinkled it upon Aaron, and upon his garments, and upon his sons, and upon his sons' garments with him; and sanctified Aaron, and his garments, and his sons, and his sons' garments with him.

Answer (score 2):

The word translated "consecration" is מִלֻּא (millu) meaning "setting" or "installation" and has two different uses:

1. It can mean a setting for a stone, eg, Ex 25:7, 35:9, 27, 1 Chron 29:2, etc
2. Setting something or someone apart for a special use in the sense that the object or person is installed as a consecrated person as a priest.

In this latter sense, we have:

**A. Animals** that were set apart and installed or consecrated for a special purpose, usually sacrifice, eg, Ex 29:22, 26, 27, 31, 34, Lev 7:37, 8:22, 28, 29, 31.  Note that such consecration animals were used as part of the ordination/consecration of the priests, and, to remind them and the people that they were consecrated priests.

**B. Priests** - consecrated/ordained = set apart as holy

> Lev 8:33 - And you shall not go outside the door of the tabernacle of
> meeting for seven days, until the days of your consecration are ended.
> For seven days he shall consecrate you.

This is part of the consecration ceremony use to initiate/install a priest.  Such consecration rams were also used as food for the priests (Lev 29:31) to remind them and the people of their on-going consecration.